# angular Form input with variable amount of parameters

Tags: angular

I'm writing a program where i could get 1 or more names of genes in my input form. if I get one, I want to run a certain API link to my backend. If I get more, I want to run a different one. What would be the best way to handle this? I want the user to be able to type a list like: cd19 or4f5 ms4a1   and then press the submit button.

Would the best way be to have my onSubmit handle both a single and multiple arguments or should I use a radio button so the user can specify if they are going to provide 1 or more arguments? If possible I would prefer the first option, because it looks cleaner in the frontend. Feel free to given other suggestions of things i haven't thought of yet.

```html
//my current form that can only accept a single argument at this moment.
<div class="container">
  <h1>Clustertool gene(s) input</h1>
  <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="gene">gene(s) </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gene" [(ngModel)]="model.gene" #gene="ngModel" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!form.$valid"> Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

this method calls my service which sends an API request to my backend

```js
onSubmit() {
    if(this.model.gene)
    this.clustertoolService.getCell(this.model.gene).subscribe(val => {
      this.cell = val;
      this.clusterCell();
    });
  };
```

this is my service that at this moment can only ask for a single gene. I'm going to add a second method that use multiple but i'm not sure how to do this, maybe a for loop that adds "+'?gene='+gene"  for every argument provided?

```js
export class ClustertoolService {
  private clusterUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.clusterUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/clustertool/singleGene';
  }
  getCell(gene: string): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get(this.clusterUrl+'?gene='+gene);

  }

}
```

my controller class that calls the backend.

```java
@RequestMapping("/clustertool")
public class ClusterController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/singleGene", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public ArrayList singleGeneResponse(@RequestParam String gene){
        return DatabaseRetriever.getSingleGene(gene);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/multipleGenes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ArrayList multipleGeneResponse(@RequestParam List<String> genes){
        return DatabaseRetriever.getMultipleGenes(genes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Allowing a user to add multiple items into a single form field would mean that you would need to parse apart all of the goofiness that they type. You may want to look into adding a plus at the end of the gene field to let the user add as many additional form fields as they need. IMHO

Comment: I have had discussions with some end users, and they liked to be able to just ctrl+v a list of genes and press the button, so if possible I try to make it like that. And lets say they want to add 20-30 genes, then it would be pretty annoying having to press an add button after every single one

Answer (score 0):

**Split your string into an array, and check the size**

```js
getCell(geneString: string): Observable<any> {
    const urlRoot = 'http://localhost:8080/clustertool/';
    const geneArray = geneString.split(' ');

    return this.http.get(
        urlRoot + (geneArray.length === 1 ? 'singleGene' : 'multipleGenes'),
        {params: {gene: geneString}}
    );
}
```

Note that query parameters should ideally be specified as an object passed to the `params` property of the `options` argument of `get()` rather than included in the URL string. If your query parameters need to be different depending on if you want the single or multi endpoint, this can be handled by similar conditional

Comment: Also note that this solution doesn't check for an empty string, i.e. `geneArray.length` would be 0 and a call would be made to the 'multiple' endpoint - this is something you might want to guard against even though it's a required field in your form, you might possibly want to use this function elsewhere later down the line

Comment: how would i receive/catch those params? i edited my post to show your my controller class.

Comment: @Mapijs under the hood `get()` will append the params to URL to create the same request as if you passed them as part of the URL string, it's just cleaner to keep the URL and parameters separate and let HttpClient build the request before firing it

Comment: i'm sorry, i still don't fully understand how the params work, i tried your piece of code exactly like you had written it. but it gives me this error: https://imgur.com/a/CZGT3bl that's the error it gives me when i hover on geneString, if i hover on gene it says cannot find name gene, because in your code you no longer take in gene as parameter in getCell

Comment: @Mapijs are you sure you've got two sets of braces: `{params: {gene: geneString}}`? This should create an object which has a property named 'params', the value of which is an object (of type HttpParams, although not explicitly stated) which has a single property named 'gene', the value of that being what was passed into `getCell` as 'geneString'